# knowing which validation has an error in Request Context callback

Tags: jsf, primefaces

on my form

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{pointController.selected.name}" title="#{bundle.CreatePointTitle_name}" required="true" />

<h:inputText id="term" value="#{pointController.selected.term}" title="#{bundle.CreatePointTitle_term}" required="true" />

<p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" action="#{pointController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreatePointSaveLink}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" />
```

javascript

```
function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {  
    if(args.validationFailed) {  
        alert("failed");
    }  
}
```

how will i know which of the input fields are not inputted or is having a validation problem?

Comment: There are many different ways. What's the functional requirement? Then we can propose the right way.

Comment: example the name field is blank and user press the commandbutton to create, how will i know that specific field was blank in the handleComplete function?

Comment: Yes, you already asked that. But you didn't explain the *why*. Why exactly do you need to know about the specific field? What exactly do you want to do with this information?

Comment: so i can properly output the specific field that has errors. like, name is blank, please input name. or if term is blank, then the error would be please input term and add some red borders on the specific input. etc. but i dont want the validation to be a javascript

Comment: Why don't you just use `<h:message>`/`<p:message>` to let JSF display the message and `<h:inputText styleClass>` or `<p:inputText>` for the style? See also e.g. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/messages.jsf Just let JSF do the thing it is designed for instead of homegrowing it with strange JavaScript workarounds.